# DOM Transitions not working on different resolution screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a scrolling effect such that when i scroll to the second page, only then will the download button will fade in, and on scrolling to third page, contribute button fades in. I have a laptop with screen resolution of 1366 x 768, but when my friend opened the website, he could not see the transition unless he zoomed in. His screen resolution was 1920 x 1080. 
Now how do i ensure that as soon as the user scrolls down to the location where the download/contribute buttons are hidden, then only the buttons fade into visibility.(so as to say, a method to know when did the element appear into view of window.)
PS. no jQuery please. pure JS solution wanted. Also it will be great if one can explain why this problem is happening in screens of different resolution.

```js
var download = document.getElementById("download");
var contribute = document.getElementById("contribute");
document.addEventListener("scroll", checkVisible);

function checkVisible() {
  var scr = window.pageYOffset;
  if (scr >= 400) {
    download.style.opacity = "1";
    download.style.left = "80%";
  }
  if (scr >= 900) {
    contribute.style.opacity = "1";
    contribute.style.left = "5%";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
}
#page1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#title {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 2px black, 0 1px 2px black, -1px 0 2px black, 0 -1px 2px black;
}
#fadetitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#title h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -5px;
}
#aboutsite {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 0;
  color: white;
  top: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#page2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#downloadtext {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 160px;
  left: 35%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
.choice {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #4d94ff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
.choice p {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0052cc;
}
#download {
  top: 225px;
  left: 85%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, left 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s;
}
#page3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
#contribute {
  top: 225px;
  left: 1%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, left 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s;
}
#contributetext {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 160px;
  left: 25%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page1">
    <div id="fade"></div>
    <div id="title">
      <div id="fadetitle"></div>
      <h1</h1>
    </div>
    <p id="aboutsite"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="page2">
    <a id="download" class="choice" href="#">
      <p>DOWNLOAD</p>
    </a>
    <p id="downloadtext"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="page3">
    <a id="contribute" class="choice" href="contribute.html" target="_blank">
      <p>CONTRIBUTE</p>
    </a>
    <p id="contributetext"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have a look at this demo i did sometime ago to show hide an element as you scroll to a specific part of the page. Its using Jquery so if you want pure JS convert it to the equivalent code -- http://jsfiddle.net/b2sjk9pL/

Comment: How did you come up with the 400 and 900 values?

Comment: When i scrolled down on my screen, i did `console.log(scr)` each time (inside the function), and console showed 400 and 900 at the place where i wanted the buttons to fade in.